# js2 auto complete not working on emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, js2-mode

I started using Emacs a couple weeks ago. I installed js2-mode on emacs and works like a charm, but now I would like to have autocompletion when working in there.

I already installed ac-js2-mode, but when I work in js2-mode I don't see any completion at all. Any ideas?

Edit: I installed and enabled auto-complete-mode, but when I'm typing a variable it says in the minibuffer the following error:

"auto-complete error: (void variable ac-source-js2)

Comment: Yes: read the docs, make sure you've followed them, and if it still doesn't work, file an issue.

Comment: did you ever get an answer? I opened an issue here: https://github.com/ScottyB/ac-js2/issues/21

Comment: by following the issue link above, I found the solution that worked for me as well:  "just replace line 285 ac-js2.el with this `(eval '(ac-define-source "js2"`"